# Status model design pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I'm running into problems implementing statuses for a model. This is probably due to wrong design.

There is a model which has a status. There can be multiple instances of the model and only a few predefined statuses (like: created, renewed, retrieved etc.). For each individual status there is some calculation logic for the model. E.g. `model.cost()` is differently calculated for each status.

I'd like to have ActiveRecord automatically set the correct `model_status_id` when saving a model. I think in the ideal situation I could do something like this:

```
model.status = StatusModel.retrieved
```

and

```
case status
  when renewed
    # ...
  when retrieved
    # ..
end
```

Thinking i need to save the status in the model row in the database this is what i've got now:

```
ModelStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :models
Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model_status
```

However this is giving me a lot of issues in the code. Anyone having some good ideas or patterns for this?

Comment: If the statuses are pre-defined, would it not be sufficient for you to store them as constants in the code as opposed to in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not keep the status part of the actual model? If they are predefined, that's not too much work:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  STAT_CREATED   = 1 
  STAT_RENEWED   = 2
  STAT_RETRIEVED = 4

  validates_inclusion_of :status,
                         :in => [1, 2, 4]


  def created?
    status & STAT_CREATED
  end

  def renewed?
    status & STAT_RENEWED
  end

  def retrieved?
    status & STAT_RETRIEVED
  end

end
```

This way, you could either test the model instance directly (e.g. if @model.created?) or write your case statements like that:

```
case @model.status
when Model::STAT_CREATED
...
when Model::STAT_RENEWED
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks pretty logical. I sometimes just think way too complex.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe seems like a perfect case for a state machine.

There are many Ruby state machine implementations. You can see a fairly representative list at [ruby-toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/state_machines.html)

When defining a state machine you can define several **States** and **transitions**. Each **transitions** taking your model from one state to another executing some code along the way. The **DSL** for it is usually quite nice.

Your example would look like

```
model.retrieve!
```

This will change the mode status from whatever it was to **retrieved** or throw an exception if current status doesn't transition to **retrieved**.

Answer (score 1):

Also try taking a look at the [`acts_as_state_machine`](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/acts_as_state_machine) plugin. I recently used it on a project and it worked well.